# How to display the selected date from the calendar using react-calendar-pane?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, calendar

I'm still fairly new to react & I'm using a simple create-react-app to display a calendar that is using react-calendar-pane (https://github.com/tomkp/react-calendar-pane). I'm trying to do something as when a user selects a date in the calendar, the date appears above the calendar. I've got the following in my App.js file:

```
import Calendar from 'react-calendar-pane';
import moment, { calendarFormat } from 'moment';
import date from 'react-calendar-pane';

<div className="App">
  <header className="App-header">
    <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
    <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to React</h1>
  </header>
  <p> The date you've selected is: this.props.onClick{date}</p>
  <Calendar date={moment("23/10/2015", "DD/MM/YYYY")} onSelect={this.onSelect} />
</div>
```

I've come to this conclusion from trying to understand the react-calendar-pane component but it's simply not working with errors like "Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `onSelect` is marked as required in `Calendar`, but its value is `undefined`.
    in Calendar (at App.js:20)
    in App (at index.js:7)"

I feel like I'm approaching it in a slightly wrong way so any suggestions or solutions will be immensely appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Can you figure it out using `console.log` in `onSelect` function. Consider, `onSelect = (value, date, index) => {console.log(value + date + index)}`. Any one of these three value will give the selected date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are receiving the error you mentioned because you haven't defined `this.onSelect`. `Calendar` requires an `onSelect` prop; this is so that when you select a date, it can pass it back to the `onSelect` function. You have not written the contents of `onSelect` function and therefore it is `undefined`. That is why you receive that error.

The first thing to do, therefore is to write the `onSelect` function. `Calendar` will call the `onSelect` function whenever a date is selected and it will pass the date value back to the function. If you write `onSelect` function like this:

```
onSelect=(e)=>{
  console.log(e);
}
```

and pass it to the `Calendar` as you have done you can see in the `console` that whenever you click on a date, that date is displayed as a `moment` object.

Now since we have to display the date we can store it in our `state`. We save it in our state so that whenever we click another date the `state` will change and our displayed date also will change.

So create a state object:

```
  constructor(){
   super();
   this.state={
    selectedDate:moment(),
   }
 }
```

We have initialized `selectedDate` with `moment()`. This is so that if no date is selected it will display today's date.

Now we change our `onSelect` function to

```
onSelect=(e)=>{
 this.setState({selectedDate:e})
}
```

This will set the date to the selected date whenever we click on a date in the `Calendar`.

Now to display the date, you have to change your

`<p> The date you've selected is: this.props.onClick{date}</p>`

to

`<p> The date you've selected is: {this.state.selectedDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD')} </p>`

This will display `this.date.selectedDate`. `format` is to convert the object into a string in the specific format mentioned.

Now the final code should look something like this

```js
import React from 'react'
import Calendar from 'react-calendar-pane';
import moment, { calendarFormat } from 'moment';
import date from 'react-calendar-pane';

class StackOverflow extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state={
      selectedDate:moment(),
    }
  }
  onSelect=(e)=>{
    this.setState({selectedDate:e})
  }
  render () {
    return(
      <div>
        <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to React</h1>
        </header>
        <p> The date you've selected is: {this.state.selectedDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD')} </p>
        <Calendar date={moment("23/10/2015", "DD/MM/YYYY")} onSelect={this.onSelect} />
      </div>

      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default StackOverflow;
```

Comment: Thank you! This is very well written & explained. Such beautiful code, thank you so very much! From this I plan on extending this feature further to be able to pick 2 dates, essentially a to and from date. Is that possible from the above example?

Comment: Yeah, you can do that. You just have to have something like `endDate` in your state and save the second date to it. There are alternate date range pickers which you can use to select a range of dates. You can try https://github.com/airbnb/react-dates